# Sequence with infinite range and 3 accumulation points

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a task about limits and accumulation points, but I'm a little bit confused about it. The task is the following:

I'm asked to find a sequence with 3 accumulation points, but with an infinite range. Also, for each accumulation point, I should find a monotone subsequence converging to that point.

I have an assumption that such sequence can be described as S<sub>n</sub> = {2, 1, 0, 4, 2, 1, 0, 6, 2, 1, 0, ...}
and the subsequences are like {4, 2, 1, 0}, {4, 2, 1}, {4, 2}, since 2, 1 and 0 are accumulation points.

Am I right or I completely miss a point of task?

Comment: The subsequences will be $\{4,4,4,4,\dots\}$, $\{2,2,2,2,\dots\}$, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your accumulation points are correct.

Your sun sequences are the constant subsequences $$ 0,0,0,...$$,$$1,1,1,....$$ and $$2,2,2,.....$$,